# domain unlocking with authentications tools

Tags: windows, azure

I realised that we often get tickets from managers asking to unlock users. I would like to know if there are tools in AD or Azure to be able to provide the ability for those users to be able to unlock their own domain accounts with authentication.

Giving that user the ability to be able to unlock themselves without IT intervention, I would assume a lot safer than giving out details to their immediate managers.

Answer (score 2):

Azure has a self-service password reset feature that sounds like it hits your marks.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/quickstart-sspr

The users will have to enroll additional authentication information (security questions, or multi-factor points).  But in the event of a lock out, they can use the SSPR option to answer a couple of questions and get back into their account.  With a quick group-policy change, there is even a reset button on the Win 10 login screen.

Comment: We dont allow users to use their phones, you mentioned that "With a quick group-policy change, there is even a reset button on the Win 10 login screen." How would I go about doing that, is there any website I can check to see a guide for that?

Comment: Sure @Mohammad, there is a whole chapter from Microsoft on the Windows Client portion: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-windows

The easy way (at least what we did) was to put the registry value they point out into a GPO and deploy it to the workstations.

Comment: @Mohammad  I googled it.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-sspr-windows